# Randomize samples in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have 10 products and their sales observations listed in Google sheets such as sales time, location, no. of units.

For audit purposes I want to pick 10 samples of each product with 10 random observations.

Can this be done in Excel/Sheets?

Currently I have been doing this manually by filtering/sorting using the rand() function. I am looking for help to randomize this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same line as ztiaa, f you need ten of each product:

```
=LET(random,SORT(A2:E,RANDARRAY(ROWS(A2:A)),1), REDUCE(A1:E1,TOCOL(UNIQUE(A2:A),1),LAMBDA(h,product,{h;SORTN(FILTER(random,INDEX(random,,1)=product),10)})))
```

It randomises the range first, and then stacks with REDUCE and SORTN a maximum of 10 values per product. Change A2:E and A1:E1 with as many columns as you need, and A2:A with the actual column of the product

Comment: Thank you so much for this!! I had been looking around for this for so long.. This makes a task a lot more easier for me!! Can't thank enough :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SORTN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en) in combination with [`RANDARRAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9211904?hl=en&sjid=15000551835438193941-EU).

```
=SORTN(A1:A,10,,RANDARRAY(ROWS(A1:A)),)
```

This formula picks 10 random values from the range A1:A.